# How to import an arff file to a pandas df and later convert it to arff again

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, weka, arff

I want to preprocess a data base with scikit learn from an arff file, and later use on an python-weka-wrapper3 model the preprocessed data base, so I need a function to load the arff as df or transform the arff to csv, and later again download the edited df on an arff or transform a csv to arff.

Some people recomend https://github.com/renatopp/liac-arff (liac-arff) but I don't know how to do that with this library.

So, if someone knows any function or some code well explained on python3 I'll apreciate.

In my case I tried with this function:

```
def arff2csv(arff_path, csv_path=None):
    with open(arff_path, 'r') as fr:
        attributes = []
        if csv_path is None:
            csv_path = arff_path[:-4] + 'csv'  # *.arff -> *.csv
        write_sw = False
        with open(csv_path, 'w') as fw:
            for line in fr.readlines():
                if write_sw:
                    fw.write(line)
                elif '@data' in line:
                    fw.write(','.join(attributes) + '\n')
                    write_sw = True
                elif '@attribute' in line:
                    #print(line.split(' ')[2])
                    attributes.append(line.split(' ')[1])  # @attribute attribute_tag numeric

        print("Convert {} to {}.".format(arff_path, csv_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay within the scikit-learn ecosystem, you could have a look at the [sklearn-weka-plugin](https://github.com/fracpete/sklearn-weka-plugin) library, which uses [python-weka-wrapper3](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3) under the hood.

BTW python-weka-wrapper3 can create datasets directly [from numpy matrices](https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/weka.core.html?highlight=create_instances_from_matrices#weka.core.dataset.create_instances_from_matrices). Examples: [[1]](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3-examples/blob/8e8422eeda99be885ba67a3a54a53cd7ee35f860/src/wekaexamples/core/dataset.py#L176), [[2]](https://github.com/fracpete/python-weka-wrapper3-examples/blob/8e8422eeda99be885ba67a3a54a53cd7ee35f860/src/wekaexamples/core/dataset.py#L186)

Answer (score 0):

I found this  answer on AV to solve my problem of *loading the arff data format into pandas dataframe*.

> https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/loading-arff-type-files-in-python/27419/2

```
from scipy.io import arff
import pandas

data = arff.loadarff('data_file_name.arff')
df = pandas.DataFrame(data[0])
```